# SSL endpoint for Heroku does not resolve

Tags: ssl, heroku, meteor

I am trying to add SSL to my app that is hosted on Heroku but I am getting the error:

`Resolving trust chain... failed
 !    Unable to read PEM file: No such file or directory - PEM`

My steps:

`heroku addons:create ssl`

`heroku certs:add PEM KEY`

error:

`Resolving trust chain... failed
 !    Unable to read PEM file: No such file or directory - PEM`

Anyone have any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually typing `heroku certs:add PEM KEY`?

If so you need to replace the words PEM KEY with the filename of your PEM key...

e.g.

`heroku certs:add my-site.pem`

The PEM key file is a certificate generated by you or a certificate authority.

Comment: Hi - so suppose my site site (with the subdomain) is http://myappname.mycompanyname.org, i would type `heroku certs:add myappname.mycompanyname.org.pem`?

Comment: Only if you have a file called `myappname.mycompanyname.org.pem` in your current working directory. Are you self-signing a certificate or are you looking to purchase one from a 'real' CA? e.g. Comodo / Verisign / Thwarte / GeoTrust etc. etc. If you don't have a certificate yet I suggest you do some further research. It's not really as simple as clicking 'Add SSL'. Start with https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#acquire-ssl-certificate, and if you just want a cheap Comodo certificate I'd recommend something like namecheap.com, you can get a standard certificate for about $10/year.